# Ayuda Lottie Para Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Estoy implementa lottie para animaciones en android studio , la coloque en un activity de esta manera

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
android:id="@+id/animation_view"
android:layout_width="392dp"
android:layout_height="421dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
app:lottie_fileName="rate.json"
app:lottie_imageAssetsFolder="assets"
app:lottie_loop="true" />
```

pero la animacion me va un poco lagueada no se porq jeje alguien me podra aconsejar algun tip o un profesor me supo manifestar que en el MANIFEST podria decirle al App que coja mas recursos del movil algo asi pero no encuentro ejeje ayuda por favor jeje

Comment: 1. Asegúrate de que la aplicación no realice muchas operaciones en el UI (hilo principal). Tu Lottie debe estar hecho de manera optima, puedes probar los tiempos del Lottie en el preview que te ofrece la [Aplicación de Lottie para Android](https://goo.gl/vrW5yb). Si ahi corre mal, que es su app, entonces esta mal optimizado. 2. Asegúrate de utilizar el Lottie CacheStrategy (setearlo manual, busca documentacion), sobretodo cuando tienes looping. 3. Intenta utilizar un Layout que no haga tantos re-dibujados, te recomiendo no utilizar `RelativeLayout` a menos que sea obligatorio.

Comment: Debes reducir su width y height para que no consuma tantos recursos, haz la prueba y me comentas.

Comment: muchas gracias por su comentario lo intente pero decidi quitarle la animacion lottie no resultaba y hacia super lente el navigation Drawer jejejej igual muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda me ha servido de mucho n.n

Comment: Te invito a ver este vídeo de implementación con lottie: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TIJGXS6Wos&t=23s

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que ir al archivo manifest y despues de iniciada la etiqueta  añadir la siguiente linea de código:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Con el fin de aumentar la memoria Heap que utiliza la aplicación, por lo que el encabezado de la etiqueta quedaría algo así:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```